# Question on sufficient complete statistics proof and estimators of zero

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to prove theorem 7.3.23 in Casella and Burger.

Theorem: 
Let T be a complete sufficient statistic for a parameter $\theta$, and let $\phi(T)$ be any estimator based only on T. Then $\phi(T)$ is the best unbiased estimator of its expected value.

Here is my attempt to prove this:

To show that $\phi(T)$ is best unbiased estimator for E[$\phi(T)$], I must show that $\phi(T)$ is uncorrelated with any unbiased estimator of $0$. So I must show that $Cov({\phi(T)}, W)=0$ for any W such that W is an unbiased estimator of $0$. For any W such that E[W]=0, $E[E[W|T]]=0$=>$E[W|T]=0$ by completeness of T. So $E[W|T]=0=E[W]$. So W is independent of T. So W and $\phi(T)$ are uncorrelated? So $\phi(T)$ is best unbiased for  its expected value. Is this correct?

Comment: The book seems to say that all unbiased estimators of 0, are 0. So really I have to show that W=0.

Comment: So by "unbiased estimator of 0" you mean $EW=0$ where the expectation is taken wrt all measures in the family? Because I think you need that to apply completeness as you later do.

Comment: This if a corollary of Lehmann-Scheffe theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but we are not showing that $W=0$. Note that $\mathrm{E}(W|T)$ is a function of the complete sufficient statistic $T$ with its expectation equal to $0$. Hence by definition of completeness, it must be a zero function (of $\theta$). In other words, it takes values on $\mathrm{E}(W|T=t)=0$ with probability $P(T=t)$. Hence 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}(W|T=t) - \mathrm{E}(W)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}w\{f_{W|T}(w|t) - f_W(w)\}dw = 0, 
\end{align*}
for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. In other words, $f_{W|T}(w|t)= f_W(w)$, for all $t$. The random variables $W$ and $T$ are then by definition independent.